# View SSIS .dtsx package source code not working with F7 outside project

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, visual-studio-2017

When I open a .dtsx file directly using Ctrl-O (File > Open > File), outside of a project, the F7 accelerator/shortcut/hotkey will not produce a source code window. It does work if the package is part of a project/solution (.sln).

Looking at the .dtsx file is not the same as looking at it after it is loaded into Visual Studio.

How can I view the SSIS package source after it is loaded into Visual Studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't - if you're already seeing the visual designer.

Under the View menu when I have a package opened, SSIS installed, but not in the context of an SSIS project.

[image]

Under the View menu when I have a package opened in the context of an SSIS project

[image]

We have Code, Designer and Open available to us when the project type is Integration Services.

Taking a peek at keyboard bindings in case there's something there, but it doesn't appear to be so. The F7 binding is Global for View.ViewCode

[image]

### But

What happens when you open a file in Visual Studio? It's going to try and figure out what editor it should use for the file. That's what it's doing with a .dtsx file. It's easy enough to fix though, re-open the file but specify the editor you want to use. Click the down arrow/chevron on the Open button and choose `Open With...`

[image]

In my list of available editors, I tried Automate Editor Selector (XML), XML (Text) Editor and XML (Text) Editor with Encoding and all seemed to show me the text just fine.

[image]